# Postgres function does not exist - but it does. Weird behaviour between two machines

Tags: postgresql, function

I inherited a couple of Postgres functions from a programmer. Unfortunately, I am not really fluent in that domain. I looked into it for quite some while now, but can't find any solution.

The problem is, that I had that function only on the development machine, but it should have been available on the production machine as well, but wasn't.

So, after different trials, I succeeded in getting the three functions on the production server.

These are the functions on the development machine via phppgadmin:
[image: functions on development machine, phppgadmin]

These are the functions on the production machine via phppgadmin:
[image: functions on production machine, phppgadmin]

As one can see, small difference for the get_geo_range function.

Navicat says they are indentical:

[image: navicat, development machine]

[image: navicat, production machine]

The details of the parameters, on both servers:

```
 IN agglevel int4, IN idvar int4, IN ystart int4, IN ystart2 int4, IN percapita int4, IN perc int4, IN geomtype int4, INOUT id_geo int4, INOUT "name" varchar, INOUT id_c int8, INOUT geom "postgis"."geometry", INOUT year_start int2, INOUT "value" numeric, INOUT unit varchar
```

Now, when I call the get_geo_range function:

```
SELECT min(value) as inf, max(value) as sup FROM gis.get_geo_range(1,1,2011,1,1,0,false);
```

it does work on the development machine. But the production machine spits out and error:

```
 ERROR:  function gis.get_geo_range(integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, boolean) does not exist
```

Now, I have no idea why. As far as I understand, this can be more due to the parameters passed then the non-existance of the function. But: What is the difference between that function on the development machine versus the production machine?! I have no clue. Thanks for any hints!

This is the function:

```
    DECLARE
        per_capita int;

    BEGIN

        IF (ystart2 = 1) THEN

            SELECT m.per_capita FROM "metadata"."table_main" as m where m.id_geo = idvar INTO per_capita;

            -- if requests if "per capita" then check if variable is suitable for a "per capita" calculation
            IF (percapita = 0) OR (percapita = 1 AND per_capita = 1) THEN

                CASE

                    WHEN agglevel=1 THEN -- country

                        RETURN QUERY 
                        SELECT
                            a.id_geo, 
                            a.id_country as id_zone,
                            a.year_start as Date,
                            CASE WHEN percapita=1 THEN a.value_pc ELSE a.value END AS value

                        FROM 
                            "public"."_ALL_DATA" as a                   
                            WHERE a.id_geo = idvar 
                            AND (
                                (NOT (allyear) AND a.year_start = ystart) 
                                OR (allyear)
                            );
                            --and a.year_end = %ye%

                    WHEN agglevel=3 THEN -- subregion       

                            RETURN QUERY    
                            WITH 
                            regdata AS (

                                SELECT
                                    a.id_geo,                           
                                    a.year_start,
                                    a.id_subregion,
                                    a.value,
                                    a.value_pc                      

                                FROM
                                    "public"."_SUBREGION" as a
                                    WHERE a.id_geo = idvar  
                                        AND (
                                            (NOT (allyear) AND a.year_start = ystart) 
                                            OR (allyear)
                                        )                       

                            )
                            SELECT
                                a.id_geo,
                                a.id_subregion as id_zone,
                                a.year_start,
                                CASE WHEN percapita=1 THEN a.value_pc ELSE a.value END AS value

                            FROM regdata as a;  

                    WHEN agglevel=2 THEN -- region

                            RETURN QUERY    
                            WITH 
                            regdata AS (

                                SELECT
                                    a.id_geo,  
                                    a.year_start,
                                    a.id_region,
                                    a.value,
                                    a.value_pc                      

                                FROM
                                    "public"."_REGION" as a
                                    WHERE a.id_geo = idvar  
                                    AND (
                                        (NOT (allyear) AND a.year_start = ystart) 
                                        OR (allyear)
                                    )               

                            )
                            SELECT
                                a.id_geo, 
                                a.id_region as id_zone,
                                a.year_start,
                                CASE WHEN percapita=1 THEN a.value_pc ELSE a.value END AS value

                            FROM regdata as a;

                    END CASE;
                END IF;



            ELSE   -- calculate difference between two years

                RETURN QUERY
                select 
                        g1.id_geo,
                        g1.id_zone,
                        g1.year_start,
                        round(CASE WHEN perc = 1    
                                    THEN 
                                        CASE WHEN g1.value = 0
                                        THEN 100    -- percentage difference
                                        ELSE ((g2.value - g1.value)/g1.value)*100 END
                                    ELSE (g2.value - g1.value) END,2) AS value          -- absolute difference

                FROM 
                    metadata.get_geo_range(agglevel,idvar,ystart,1,percapita, 0, allyear) as g1,
                    metadata.get_geo_range(agglevel,idvar,ystart2,1,percapita, 0, allyear) as g2

                WHERE
                        g1.id_geo = g2.id_geo 
                        and g1.id_zone = g2.id_zone;


            END IF;

    END;
```

**EDIT** (after using \sf gis.get_geo_range):

The development server returns this:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gis.get_geo_range(agglevel integer, idvar integer, ystart integer, ystart2 integer, percapita integer, perc integer, allyear boolean)
     RETURNS TABLE(id_geo integer, id_zone smallint, year_start smallint, value numeric)
```

The production server this:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gis.get_geo_range(agglevel integer, idvar integer, ystart integer, ystart2 integer, percapita integer, perc integer, allyear boolean, INOUT id_geo integer, INOUT id_zone smallint, INOUT year_start smallint, INOUT value numeric)
     RETURNS SETOF record
```

Comment: There is a possible difference in the schemanames ("gis" versus "metadata") between dev and production. Check the schema search_path on both.

Comment: @joop: Seems to be the same: dev: public, metadata, admin, gis, tablefunc, postgis, topology.   prod: public, metadata, admin, gis, gegslive, tablefunc, postgis, topology (gegslive not important here)

Comment: And the other usual suspect is mixed-case identifiers + frontends (not) quoting them. Best way to find out is `pg_dump --schema-only dbname` on both machines, and comparing the resulting output. Plus: check the Postgres logs.

Comment: _"What is the difference between that function on the development machine versus the production machine?!"_ -  phpPgAdmin showed you the difference. Navicat is lying (or, more likely, you accidentally pointed it at the wrong server).

Comment: @NickBarnes: The difference is that there are more parameters. That's clear. But no idea why, as it's the same function. The first set of parameters are IN-params, the second set are InOut-params. But that doesn't really help me. And: Navicat may be lying - but surely these are from the two relevant machines.

Comment: @luftikus: OK, I'm not sure what's going on in Navicat, but there is clearly some difference which it's not reporting; if the functions were truly identical, then the phpPgAdmin output would be identical. Try connecting to each database with [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) and comparing the output of `\sf gis.get_geo_range`.

Comment: @NickBarnes: Thanks for that. I've pasted the code above at the bottom of my question. Looks like somewhat of a difference. Why that? I have no clue, as the production code should be a copy of the development code. Then my question is perhaps rather: a) is the function (with its parameters) coded correctly on the development machine? and b) if so, how can I get it over to the production machine correctly? I did a dump, and executed the code - and voilà, this is what I get...

Comment: If the functions have different arguments (-types) they are different functions, even if they happen to have the same name. Ergo: the (first) function does not exist on the production server.

Comment: @luftikus: a) I would imagine that the dev version is correct, given that it's the one which actually works. b) Drop the function on the production server, and run the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement from `psql` (and as always, make sure you have a backup of your production database before taking advice from strangers on the internet ;) ).

Comment: As for _why_ this happened, it's probably a bug in the tool you used to dump the function definitions; I have had trouble in the past with admin tools which fail to get these `RETURNS TABLE` clauses right. `psql`, being officially supported by the Postgres project, is by far the safest option in cases like this. Better yet, keep your `CREATE FUNCTION` script in source control, and make sure you run the same script in your dev and production environments.